# Fetching IP address of router to which iPhone is connected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ip-address

I want to fetch the IP address of the router (WiFi access point) to which my iPhone is connected wirelessly. The code gives only the IP address of the device

Can anyone help with a piece of code?

Comment: Did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113580/objective-c-how-to-fetch-the-router-address?lq=1)?, may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy paste this code and run you will get all ip address that connected through ip address. Required Frameworks are

```
  #import <sys/types.h>
  #import <arpa/inet.h>
  #import <netdb.h>
```

in viewdidload copy paste this

```
int i=0;
 while (i>254) {
                i++;
                NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.%d",i];
            struct hostent *he;
            struct in_addr ipv4addr;

            inet_pton(AF_INET, [address UTF8String], &ipv4addr);
            he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
            if (he) {
                printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
                NSLog(@"%@",address);
                //    NSLog(@"%@",address);
            }
        }
```