# Objective C: Retrieve Router address?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, network-programming

Trying to fetch the router address in an app.

I found this post [Objective-C : How to fetch the router address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113580/objective-c-how-to-fetch-the-router-address) 
but the author of the answer said that the method is not recommended as calls might change without notice.

Could you please help me with a more reliable method ?

Comment: check out this link, might be helpful to you

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530322/fetching-ip-address-of-router-to-which-iphone-is-connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to think that the code in that answer will stop working any time soon.  The APIs that it uses are documented and have been around for a long time.

Documentation: start with [`man 3 sysctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctl.3.html).  Also see the book [*TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 2: The Implementation*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163354X).