# Why am I unable to read iOS WiFi address?

Tags: ios, titanium, wifi

I need to read my iOS device's Wifi address. But the code I've tried is failing on Simulator and on iPad 2 / v6.1.3

I'm working in Titanium, so first I tried Titanium.Platform.address. That comes back undefined.

Then I started working in Objective C. But this function is also failing to get the WiFi IP. I know that WiFi is on because the internet works and my networking project works if I manually enter the device's address.

```
- (id)networkAddress
{
    NSLog(@"[INFO] getting network IP");

    BOOL success;
    struct ifaddrs * addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs * cursor;

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success) {

        NSLog(@"[INFO] getifaddrs() success");

        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET && (cursor->ifa_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK) == 0) // this second test keeps from picking up the loopback address
            {
                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cursor->ifa_name];
                if ([name isEqualToString:@"en0"]) { // found the WiFi adapter
                    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)cursor->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }

            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

What can prevent me from reading the WiFi IP address?

Comment: How is that function failing (i.e. what is the value of `success`), and is it still failing if you remove the check for `"en0"` in the interface name?

Comment: I added two log traces. The first gets called - it verifies that the function has been called. But the second NSLog never happens. getifaddrs(&addrs) is not returning 0.

Comment: Check `errno` if `getifaddrs()` failed.

Comment: errno = 6 ENXIO No such device or address.  Input or output on a special file referred to a device that did not exist, or made a request beyond the limits of the device.  This error may also occur when, for example, a tape drive is not online or no disk pack is loaded on a drive.

Comment: This is working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530322/fetching-ip-address-of-router-to-which-iphone-is-connected/6530703#6530703