# how to know gateway address of current connected wifi

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know gateway address of current connected wifi through objective C programming.

I have gone through some online reference in stackoverflow but none of them is useful. Please know me the.

As for now I am able to get IP address, Mask but has been stuck in gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically make a call to execute a terminal command using system(); and parse the output, or follow the advice in this question: [Objective-C : How to fetch the router address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113580/objective-c-how-to-fetch-the-router-address)